# shared expressions in scriptlet

Tags: jasper-reports, expression, scriptlet

We are using a `scriptlet` as a way to maintain global expressions that can be leveraged by a pool of `iReport` developers. Came across an issue where we have created a variable in the `scriptlet` that is based on two other variables that are defined in the report. The issue is that the two report level variables always seem to get resolved after the system variable. Not sure if by default `iReport` will always resolve a system variable before local variables. We tried adjusting the `EVALUATION` time for the system variable to something other then (`NOW`) but that doesn't seem to have any effect......any suggestions on how make the system variable calculate after the 2 local variables?